# smartgwt export listgrid datasource to excel file

Tags: smartgwt

I want to export my ListGrid DataSource to Excel file and I am using excel file because i want to populate my listgrid fields in excel file. does any one know how to do it. it will be great help to me.

Thanks Ankit.

Comment: Which edition of Smartgwt do you use? LGPL or Pro/Power/EE?

Comment: hey I am using Smartgwt LGPL 1.2 version

Answer (score 3):

Being an amateur, even I wanted to do the same thing but had very few option in SmartGwt.  Only the SmartGwt Pro/Power/EE version has such functionality. However I have found a solution to this and the code is attached as there are no examples out there yet and if anyone is new to GWT like me, you would have to spend a whole time cracking this. The following sample code is simple and easy to understand.

```
 public class GridToCSV implements EntryPoint {



    /**
     * Create a remote service proxy to talk to the server-side Greeting
     * service.
     */
    private final GreetingServiceAsync greetingService = GWT.create(GreetingService.class);

    public void onModuleLoad() {

        DataSource dataSource = new DataSource();
        dataSource.setDataFormat(DSDataFormat.JSON);
        dataSource.setDataURL("data/countries_small.js");

        DataSourceTextField nameField = new DataSourceTextField("name", "Name");
        DataSourceTextField populationfield = new DataSourceTextField(
                "population", "Population");
        DataSourceTextField areaField = new DataSourceTextField("total_area",
                "Total Area");
        DataSourceTextField governmentField = new DataSourceTextField(
                "government", "Government");

        dataSource.setFields(nameField, populationfield, areaField,
                governmentField);

        final ListGrid grid = new ListGrid();
        grid.setDataSource(dataSource);
        grid.setWidth100();
        grid.setHeight(150);
        grid.setAutoFetchData(true);

        IButton button = new IButton("Export CSV");
        button.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
            public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
                StringBuilder exportedCSV = exportCSV(grid);
                System.out.println(exportedCSV);
                sendTOServer(exportedCSV);
                // Window.Location(listGrid.exportData());
            }

        });
        //grid.draw();
        //button.draw();

        VLayout layout = new VLayout(); layout.addMember(button);
        layout.addMember(grid); 
        layout.addMember(button);
        layout.setWidth100();
        layout.draw();


    }

    private StringBuilder exportCSV(ListGrid listGrid) {
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder(); // csv data in here

        // column names
        ListGridField[] fields = listGrid.getFields();
        for (int i = 0; i < fields.length; i++) {
            ListGridField listGridField = fields[i];
            stringBuilder.append("\"");
            stringBuilder.append(listGridField.getName());
            stringBuilder.append("\",");
        }
        stringBuilder.deleteCharAt(stringBuilder.length() - 1); // remove last
                                                                // ","
        stringBuilder.append("\n");

        // column data
        ListGridRecord[] records = listGrid.getRecords();
        for (int i = 0; i < records.length; i++) {
            ListGridRecord listGridRecord = records[i];
            ListGridField[] listGridFields = listGrid.getFields();
            for (int j = 0; j < listGridFields.length; j++) {
                ListGridField listGridField = listGridFields[j];
                stringBuilder.append("\"");
                stringBuilder.append(listGridRecord.getAttribute(listGridField
                        .getName()));
                stringBuilder.append("\",");
            }
            stringBuilder.deleteCharAt(stringBuilder.length() - 1); // remove
                                                                    // last ","
            stringBuilder.append("\n");
        }
        return stringBuilder;
    }

    private void sendTOServer(StringBuilder csvText) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String csv = csvText.toString();
        final HTML serverResponseLabel = new HTML();
        greetingService.greetServer(csv, new AsyncCallback<String>() {
            public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {

            }

            public void onSuccess(String result) {
                // dialogBox.setText("Remote Procedure Call");
                serverResponseLabel.removeStyleName("serverResponseLabelError");
                serverResponseLabel.setHTML(result);
                 Window.open(result, "_blank", "");
                // dialogBox.center();
                // closeButton.setFocus(true);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

**GreetingService.java**

```
    @RemoteServiceRelativePath("greet")
public interface GreetingService extends RemoteService {
    String greetServer(String name) throws IllegalArgumentException;
}
```

**GreetingServiceAsync.java**

```
    public interface GreetingServiceAsync {
    void greetServer(String input, AsyncCallback<String> callback)
            throws IllegalArgumentException;
}
```

**GreetingServiceImpl.java**

```
    @SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class GreetingServiceImpl extends RemoteServiceServlet implements
        GreetingService {

    String url;

    public String greetServer(String input) throws IllegalArgumentException {
        FileWriter fw;
        try {
            fw = new FileWriter("WriteTest.csv");
            PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(fw);
            // Write to file for the first row
            url = "http://127.0.0.1:8888/WriteTest.csv";
            pw.print(input);
            pw.flush();
            // Close the Print Writer
            pw.close();
            // Close the File Writer
            fw.close();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return url;

    }
}
```

The above code works and its easy and simple to understand. I have used the default Test Project Structure of GWT for all to understand. The code used for the ListGrid part was used from the smartgwt showcase [ListGrid JSON Integration](http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/showcase/#json_integration_category_simple). Kindly let me know if you need anymore clarity for the solution provided.

Answer (score 0):

You could set up a seperat (non rpc) Servlet and send the data which has to be exported via http POST to the servlet (e.g. via a GWT `FormPanel`). On server side you can create an exel file with [Apache POI](http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwtee/showcase/#excel_export) and provide it for downloading.

Pro/Power/EE of SmartGwt has such a function included (see [this](http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwtee/showcase/#excel_export) showcase).

Answer (score -1):

You do not need to do this manually.... It has been done for you....

check this out:

http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwtee/showcase/#excel_export

It is a working example